# Key mapping problems for 2 player game

Tags: python, events, keyboard, pygame

I'm making a 2-player maze runner game, and I have come to some trouble with keyboard events. If both players hit a key at the same time, only player 1 moves, because my code tests for player1's events first. Is there a way in python and pygame to check for both events simultaneously? Here's a part of my player1 class:

```
class Player( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super( Player, self ).__init__()
        self.size = self.w,self.h = 75,75
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( self.size ) )
        self.image.fill( white )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.move_y = 0
        self.move_x = 0

        self.speed = 5

        self.player = True
        self.alive = True

        self.level = None



    def update( self, collidable = pygame.sprite.Group(), event = None ):

        self.rect.x += self.move_x
        self.rect.y += self.move_y

        if not ( event == None ):
            if ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_LEFT ):
                    self.move_y = 0
                    self.move_x = -self.speed
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT ):
                    self.move_y = 0
                    self.move_x = self.speed
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_UP ):
                    self.move_x = 0
                    self.move_y = -self.speed
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_DOWN ):
                    self.move_x = 0
                    self.move_y = self.speed
```

Sorry for the block of code, but it is all necessary for you to understand how it works. I have a nearly identical class for the player 2, but with different keyboard controls(WASD instead of arrow keys).

I define my player1 and player2 classes:

```
player_object_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

p1 = Player()
p1.set_position( 40, 725 )
p1.set_image(deadpool_icon)

p2 = Player2()
p2.set_position( 525, 725 )
p2.set_image(girl_bow)
```

Then I update and draw them:

```
 p1.update( current_level.object_list, event )
 p2.update( current_level.object_list, event )
 event = None

 player_object_list.draw( window )
```

To conclude: With this code, keyboard controlled movement works fine, but it doesn't check both players' keyboard events at the same time, so if both press a key at the same time, only player1 detects the event because it updates before player2:

```
 p1.update( current_level.object_list, event )
 p2.update( current_level.object_list, event )
```

Thanks in advance,

Derek

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: In simple games (i.e. not professional competition :-) ) you do this by checking one, then the other, and processing both before you update the board. It's hard to help you with only partial code: no interaction code, no snippet of player 2's class (if he's using different controls, I don't think the classes are identical), and no driver program.

Comment: Also, your code might be more readable if you generalize your movement decisions.

Comment: Alright, I'll add more detail and more of my code. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping my comments above in mind, let's take a shot at a solution.  First of all, I want to make your code a little more general, and perhaps easier on the eyes: use a look-up table for the move translation.

```
move_translate = {
    pygame.K_LEFT: (-1, 0),
    pygame.K_RIGHT: (1, 0),
    pygame.K_UP: (0, -1),
    pygame.K_DOWN: (0, 1)
}

if event is not None:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key in move_translate:
            # dictionary.get() will improve this, 
            #    if you want to advance that far in Python syntax
            self.move_x, self.move_y = move_translate[event.key]
            self.move_x *= self.speed
            self.move_y *= self.speed

    # Here, you have to retire the event you just processed.
    # Then pass out of the first check for no event.
    # Check for another in the event queue, for player 2.
    # After this check, you can update the display.
```

Does this move you toward a solution?  Depending on the queue and interactions you're using, you may be able to put the event checks into a loop that handles all events for this time tick.

Comment: I think you meant `move_translate[event.key]`.  Your dictionary is also not closed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Testing for the events individually in one frame and then updating them works! Appreciate the help, and I'll try and add more deatial into my questions next time.